# Changes in the way a componentlink in keyword metadata is stored in the Broker for 2013

Tags: 2013-sp1, 2009, broker, keyword, metadata

We're in the process of migrating from 2009 to 2013. 
We have custom metadata stored on keywords and those keywords are published to the Broker.

Before the migration, we could apparently get the linked component of the keyword by using `keyword.getKeywordMeta().getNameValues()` and then look for the metadata field name ('link_component')

In 2013, we now have an issue where all the keyword metadata (text) fields are returned from the Broker, except for the component link.

> Has something changed in the way component links in the metadata of a
>   keyword are stored in the Broker?
>
> What's the appropriate way to retrieve a component link stored in the
>   metadata of a keyword on content delivery side, once you have the Keyword object?

**UPDATE**:
we've raised a ticket with Customer Support, cause at this moment it just looks like a bug. Will update this issue if there's more info...